# Json from file not loading the first time

Tags: json, flutter

I'm trying to get a online JSON, save it locally for offline use. The issue is that when I try to get the data from the saved JSON file, the first time I open the new "window" no data is loading, because my "goggo1" variable does not receive the new value from reading the JSON file. The funny thing is if I go back and the open it again, then "goggo1" is getting the value required to show the JSON contents.

```
class HomePagerstare extends StatefulWidget {
  Contact contact = new Contact();
  String title, content;

  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

Future<String> get getFilePath async {
  final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
  return directory.path;
}

Future<File> get getFile async {
  final path = await getFilePath;
  return File('$path/myfile.json');
}

Future<File> saveToFile(String datar) async {
  final file = await getFile;
  return file.writeAsString(datar);
}

Future<String> readFromFile() async {
  try {
    final file = await getFile;
    final String fileContents = await file.readAsString();

    return fileContents;
  } catch (e) {
    return "aici e eroare";
  }
}
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePagerstare> implements HomeContract {
  List<Note> data1 = List<Note>();
  List<Note> data2 = List<Note>();
  var goggo1 = "";
  Future<List<Note>> loadJsonData() async {
    var data = List<Note>();

    this.setState(() {
      print(goggo1);
     
      var datas = jsonDecode(goggo1);
      for (var noteJson in datas) {
        data.add(Note.fromJson(noteJson));
        Note note =
            Note(noteJson["id"], noteJson["title"], noteJson["content"]);
      }
    });

    return data;
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    print("1Nu Suntem Online");
    super.initState();
    readFromFile().then((fileContents) {
      setState(() {
        goggo1 = fileContents;
      });
    });
    print("1Nu Suntem Online");
    this.loadJsonData().then((value) {
      setState(() {
        data1.addAll(value);
        data2 = data1;
        print("2Nu Suntem Online");
      
      });
    });
    
  }
```

```
class Note {
  String title;
  String content;
  int id;
  
the note.dart

  Note(this.id, this.title, this.content);

  Note.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    title = json['title'];
    content = json['content'];
  }
}
```

Please help!

Comment: Use FutureBuilder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I could give you an idea. Try something like this,

```
readFromFile().then((fileContents) {
      setState(() {
        goggo1 = fileContents;
      });
      this.loadJsonData().then((value) {
      setState(() {
        data1.addAll(value);
        data2 = data1;
        print("2Nu Suntem Online");
      
      });
    });
});
```

Hope that works!